# SQL query to Mongo (SELECT lower entries and increment value to receive rank)

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to convert a SQL query to Mongo.

The SQL query gathers a rank for entries it determines are "lower" than the given base.

```
base_user_id = 1
base_primary = 123
base_secondary = 456789
base_update_ms = 9999999

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank FROM scores, ( SELECT @rank:=0 ) r WHERE (
        ( primary > base_primary ) OR
        ( primary = base_primary AND secondary > base_secondary ) OR
        ( primary = base_primary AND secondary = base_secondary AND last_update_ms <= base_update_ms )
) AND user_id != base_user_id ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1
```

Here how I sort a group of entries using Mongo's Java lib.

```
Sorts.orderBy(
    Sorts.descending("primary", "secondary"),
    Sorts.ascending("last_update_ms")
)
```

This works as intended, and allows for easy group lookups for things like pagination.

The issue, however, is trying to find a rank for a single document.

I've been playing around with Mongo aggregations, but no luck yet. I'd love if someone could help point me in the right direction! Thank you!

**Edit:** Here's what I came up with without using aggregate... (Not a fan of this, it's pretty slow when testing with 2m entries)

```
        Bson betterSameSecondaryFilter = Filters.or(
                Filters.lt("last_update", d.lastUpdate()), // the lower last update is better
                Filters.and(Filters.eq("last_update"), // updated at the same time (very unlikely)
                        Filters.lt("_id", d._id())) // the lower doc id is better
        );

        Bson betterSecondaryFilter = Filters.or( // only happens if primary values are equal
                Filters.gt("secondary", d.secondary()), // secondary value is higher, they're a better rank
                Filters.and(Filters.eq("secondary", d.secondary()), // secondary values are equal, compare update time
                        betterSameSecondaryFilter)
        );

        Bson betterRankFilter = Filters.or(
                Filters.gt("primary", d.primary()), // primary value is higher, they're a better rank
                Filters.and(Filters.eq("primary", d.primary()), // primary values are equal, compare secondary values
                        betterSecondaryFilter)
        );

        long rank = 1 + hiscores.countDocuments(Filters.and(
                Filters.eq("key", d.key()),
                Filters.ne("user_id", userDoc.id()),
                betterRankFilter
        ));
```

Comment: Updated main post with solution. Still looking to improve it though!